# Rails , How to santize within the Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following model

Diary.rb

```html
class Diary < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :student
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :grade
    has_many :diary_entries

    validates :diary_year, presence: true

    def self.from_student(owner, student_obj)
        new(
            user_id: owner.id,
            student_id: student_obj.id,
            grade_id: student_obj.grade_id,
 #How to add diary_year here..... 
        )
    end
      
end
```

My diary only had three attributes, user_id, grade_id, student_id... I added an extra attribute diary_year, the diary_year is a integer and I am not sure what is the right syntax to add it to the self.from_student..

My guess, but that fails.

```html
diary_year: subject_obj.diary_year
```

Here is my controller

```
def create
    @diary = Diary.from_student(current_user, @student)
    @diary.save
    redirect_to @student, notice: "Diary was successfully created."
 end
```

Comment: What do you mean by sanitize, and what is the column type for diary_year attributr?

Comment: like adding it to my params... I might be using the wrong terminology, the column type is an integer..

Comment: You need to show your controller params whitelist. Also your `diary_year` is created in the `Diary` class model. What is it? If it is auto-created off of when the dairy was created then it would just be `:diary_year: Date.today.year`

Comment: Thank you @Beartech, "diary_year: Date.today.year" that worked like magic! it's auto-created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate the field with `Date.today.year` in the method:

```
class Diary < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :student
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :grade
    has_many :diary_entries

    validates :diary_year, presence: true

    def self.from_student(owner, student_obj)
        new(
        user_id: owner.id,
        student_id: student_obj.id,
        grade_id: student_obj.grade_id,
        diary_year: Date.today.year #this populates the field automatically
        )
    end

end
```